# Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: Youtube Dapp example tutorial

Tags: solidity

EDIT: So I've narrowed it down further to the `transferFrom` function within the `stakeTokens` function. I've deployed these contracts with Remix and it seems I'm having trouble calling the `transferFrom` function from BlahCoin..... Anyone know this error or how to fix it?

I used a pretty simple tutorial on youtube to learn solidity but the transaction keeps reverting on ropsten. I can't figure out why and there doesnt seem like any good debuging tools to find the issue.

It fails when I call the stakeTokens function through Javascript. I first call the approve function which works as expected and gets posted properly then I call the stakeTokens function which fails and reverts. I'm not sure if its a problem with the stakeTokens function or the transferFrom function.

Here are my contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


import "./BlahToken.sol";

contract TokenFarm {
    string public name = "Blah Token Farm";
    address public owner;
    BlahToken public blahToken;


address[] public stakers;
mapping(address => uint) public stakingBalance;
mapping(address => bool) public hasStaked;
mapping(address => bool) public isStaking;

constructor(BlahToken _blahToken) public {
    blahToken = _blahToken;
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function stakeTokens(uint _amount) public {
    // Require amount greater than 0
    require(_amount > 0, "amount cannot be 0");

    // Trasnfer Blah Token tokens to this contract for staking
    blahToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

    // Update staking balance
    stakingBalance[msg.sender] = stakingBalance[msg.sender] + _amount;

    // Add user to stakers array *only* if they haven't staked already
    if(!hasStaked[msg.sender]) {
        stakers.push(msg.sender);
    }

    // Update staking status
    isStaking[msg.sender] = true;
    hasStaked[msg.sender] = true;
}

// Unstaking Tokens (Withdraw)
function unstakeTokens() public {
    // Fetch staking balance
    uint balance = stakingBalance[msg.sender];

    // Require amount greater than 0
    require(balance > 0, "staking balance cannot be 0");

    // Transfer Mock Dai tokens to this contract for staking
    blahToken.transfer(msg.sender, balance);

    // Reset staking balance
    stakingBalance[msg.sender] = 0;

    // Update staking status
    isStaking[msg.sender] = false;
}

// Issuing Tokens
function issueTokens() public {
    // Only owner can call this function
    require(msg.sender == owner, "caller must be the owner");

    // Issue tokens to all stakers
    for (uint i=0; i<stakers.length; i++) {
        address recipient = stakers[i];
        uint balance = stakingBalance[recipient];
        if(balance > 0) {
            blahToken.transfer(recipient, balance);
        }
    }
}
}
```

My Other contract is here for the token:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract BlahToken {
    string  public name = "Blah Token";
    string  public symbol = "BLA";
    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000; // 1 million tokens
    uint8   public decimals = 18;
event Transfer(
    address indexed _from,
    address indexed _to,
    uint256 _value
);

event Approval(
    address indexed _owner,
    address indexed _spender,
    uint256 _value
);

mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

constructor() public {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
}

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}
}
```

I would appreciate the help if anyone could help tell me why the transactions keep reverting.

Comment: What functions fail ? With what parameters ?  How do you interact with the contracts (scripts, Remix, etc) ?

Comment: We need more info/context to answer your question.

Comment: StakeTokens function is failing and I interact with it through Javascript

Comment: @Snuggles Have you solved this? The code appears to be correct. Do you have a failed transaction hash?